# Streamlit st.table display error for a mutliindex df

Tags: streamlit

```
# Create a sample multi-index DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Group 1', 'A'), ('Group 1', 'B'), ('Group 2', 'A'), ('Group 2', 'B')])
data = np.random.randn(4, 3)
columns = ['Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)
df
```

`i have a dataframe in the following form
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wt4Tt.png)
i m trying to display it in streamlit using st.table(df) but i m getting the following error
ArrowTypeError: ("object of type <class 'str'> cannot be converted to int", 'Conversion failed for column None with type object')
anyway to fix this please?

i m trying to display it in streamlit using st.table(df) but i m getting the following error
ArrowTypeError: ("object of type <class 'str'> cannot be converted to int", 'Conversion failed for column None with type object')
anyway to fix this please?

Comment: Can you create a simple example of your data and include it in an executable snippet? Streamlit doesn't support multiheader rows, so you have to do some extra manual work to convert everything to strings for display.